# django import export error in import xlsx

Tags: django, django-import-export

I don't understand why i'm getting this error when I try to insert the xlsx file. This is my model

```
class Finance(models.Model):
invoiceNumber = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, 
primary_key=True)
student = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
rollGroup = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
invoiceTo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
dob = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
schedule = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False, null=False)
totalValue = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
issueDate = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
dueDate = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
datePaid = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
amountPaid = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.invoiceNumber
```

This is my resource model

```
class FinanceResource(resources.ModelResource):

    invoiceNumber = Field(attribute='invoiceNumber', column_name='Invoice 
    Number')
    student = Field(attribute='student', column_name='Student')
    rollGroup = Field(attribute='rollGroup', column_name='Roll Group')
    invoiceTo = Field(attribute='invoiceTo', column_name='Invoice To')
    dob = Field(attribute='dob', column_name='DOB')
    gender = Field(attribute='gender', column_name='Gender')
    status = Field(attribute='status', column_name='Status')
    schedule = Field(attribute='schedule', column_name='Schedule')
    totalValue = Field(attribute='totalValue', column_name='Total             
    Value(PKR 
    ₨)')
    issueDate = Field(attribute='issueDate', column_name='Issue Date')
    dueDate = Field(attribute='dueDate', column_name='Due Date')
    datePaid = Field(attribute='datePaid', column_name='Date Paid')
    amountPaid = Field(attribute='amountPaid', column_name='Amount Paid     
    (PKR 
    ₨)')

class Meta:
    model = Finance

import_id_fields = ('invoiceNumber',)
export_order = ('invoiceNumber', 'student', 'rollGroup', 
'invoiceTo', 'dob', 'gender', 'status', 'schedule',
                'totalValue', 'issueDate', 'dueDate', 'datePaid', 
'amountPaid')

skip_unchanged = True
report_skipped = True
```

And the error im getting
[image: this is the error i keep getting]

And when i use the default primary key i get

Line number: 1 - **str** returned non-string (type int)
2, styles, harry, Spring 2020, Family, None, M, Pending, First Installment, 57000, None, 10/06/2020, None, 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\long play computers\PycharmProjects\DotsPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 559, in import_row
row_result.object_repr = force_str(instance)
File "C:\Users\long play computers\PycharmProjects\DotsPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 64, in force_str
s = str(s)
TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type int)

Comment: could you reformat your questing using code instead of screenshots?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: in the image, the error is occurring because the import id field ('id') cannot be found in the list of fields.  Is it definitely there in the source xls?

Comment: I was getting this error before using the import field for id
Currently it is import_id_fields = ('invoiceNumber')
i got so stuck that i was trying everything.

Comment: pls can you update the question so we can see what might be causing the current issue?  Is this an Update or an Insert?  Can you step through with the Pycharm debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: I have updated the question. im gettings this
[08/Jun/2020 19:36:45] "GET /admin/proto/finance/import/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3245
[08/Jun/2020 19:36:47] "POST /admin/proto/finance/import/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5860

Comment: It's very difficult to help based on what you've posted.  The 2nd error you have posted is because the code can't store a string representation of the imported instance (because it is trying to coerce `id` into a string but cannot do so).  If you can use Pycharm to set breakpoints in `import_row()` you will be able to see exactly what the error is.  Alternatively, if you can update the question with more specific information, we can help.

Comment: Hey i just fixed it. It was an identation issue as the fields were not used under class Meta. Anyways thankyou for the help and can you please look at this question of mine?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270240/django-import-export-iterate-foreign-key-on-object-creation